# Split large array into many subarrays using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So, I am using numpy and am trying to use reshape to make the amount of columns 1500 and make as many rows as it needs to satisfy the amount of data in the original array (so if I have 4500 elements, the amount of rows would be 3).

I must not be understanding how to use reshape correctly and any queries come up with nothing that helps me.

Here is my code:

```
def grayscale_pixel(hex_digit):
    gray_value = int(hex_digit, 16) * 16 + 15
    return (gray_value, gray_value, gray_value)

# Read in file arguments.
from os import sys
import numpy as np
import math

input_file_name = '0A32eTdBKayjCWhZqDOQ.bytes'

# Open input file.
try:
    file = open(input_file_name)

except IOError:
    print("The file %s does not exist." % fileName)
    sys.exit(1)

# Retrieve all of the hex digits from the file.
contents = file.read()

contents = contents.replace("?", "")

contents = "".join(contents.split())    

pixels = np.array([grayscale_pixel(digit) for digit in contents])

columns = 1500

rows = (math.floor(pixels.size/columns)) * columns

twodpixels = np.reshape(pixels[:rows*columns], (rows,columns))
```

As you can see, I am creating "pixels," which has many 1x3 matricies where:

```
([15, 15, 15],
 [15, 15, 15],
 [15, 15, 15],
 ...          )
```

I am going to be analyzing a bunch of files, but I need them all to be the same number of columns, in this case 1500.

I am also trying to make it so I don't lose any data so I was advised to cut off some of the data in pixels to make it all fit as the loss in data would be negligible. So, in order to do that I took the floor of the size of pixels and multiplied that by the 1500 columns I want to make.

What am I doing wrong as I keep getting the "ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged" error?

Comment: What do you get for `pixels[:rows*columns].shape`, `rows`? The error says that they don't correspond, so reshape does not know how to handle it.

Comment: Can't you just do `pixels.reshape((-1, columns))`. If the amount doesn't come out evenly then remove the excess rows. `pixels[:-excess].reshape((-1, columns))`. To get the excess I think you can just `excess = len(pixels) % columns`. If you want to keep the excess then make an extra row to append `append = np.zeros((1, columns)); append[0][:excess] = pixels[-excess:]` Then append the reshaped item